# Bash Script Not Adding to arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

So for some reason my script isnt adding the extra data to the arrays inside the while loops. The data is there and correctly matching but not appending to the arrays.

The input file contents is:

name:passwordhash

```
while read -r lines;
do
    HASH_COMMON=$(echo -n "$lines" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}');
    while read -r line ; 
    do
        # change seperator to colon
        IFS=: read -r NAME PASSWORD <<< "$line"
        # compare hashed password against hashed password list
        if [ "$HASH_COMMON" == "$PASSWORD" ] ; 
        then
            CRACKED_RESULT+=("$lines")
            HASH_RESULT+=("$HASH_COMMON")
            NAME_RESULT+=("$NAME")
            PASSWORD_RESULT+=("$PASSWORD")

        fi

    done < "$PASSED_FILE"
done < "$COMMON_PW"
```

output if i print the arrays outside the loop is just a single pass of data using for loop

```
for i in "${NAME_RESULT[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
    echo ""
done
```

then I am comparing the arrays later with a for loop as well

```
for isCracked in "${CRACKED_RESULT[@]}";
do
    for checkCrack in "${PASSWORD_RESULT[@]}";
    do
        one="${HASH_RESULT[isCracked]}"
        two="${PASSWORD_RESULT[checkCracked]}"

        if [ "$one" == "$two" ];
        then
            RESULT_ARRAY+=("USERNAME: ${NAME_RESULT[checkCracked]} PASSWORD:    ${CRACKED_RESULT[checkCracked]}")
        fi
        checkCrack=+1
    done
    isCracked=+1
done
```

Comment: why does it do one entry? and not the others

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I get complete results when I run it on some test files I faked up, so I second the request for an MCVE. BTW, `echo -n` isn't very reliable, I recommend `printf '%s' "$lines"` instead.

Comment: My psychic powers suggest that you're reading the arrays with `$CRACKED_RESULT` instead of the correct `"${CRACKED_RESULT[@]}"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson thats why i was a little confused. Ive added in the rest of my code.

Comment: I have it working, now the comparision loop is only putting in the first result wich is correct, multiple times